# Effects and phantom types

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

Let's say we have three objects:

```
MainObj {
  someProp: false
  toggleSomeProp: function () {
    if (this.someProp)
      this.someProp = false
    else
      this.someProp = true
  }
  ...
}

FirstObj {
  someOtherProp: ...
  doSomethingWithOtherProp: function () {...}
  ...
}

SecondObj {
  state: null
  setState: function (s) {
    this.state = s
  }
  getState: function() {
    return this.state
  }
  ...
}
```

`FirstObj` and `SecondObj` inherit `someProp` and `toggleSomeProp` from `MainObj` and extend it with their own properties and methods. `SecondObj` extends `MainObj` with state property (and get/set methods) which can be anything.

Let's also say we have two objects `FirstObjSrc` and `SecondObjSrc` which both have `getObj` method. First one returns `FirstObj` and the second one returns `SecondObj`.

That is how I see it implemented in Purescript:

```
foreign import data ObjEff :: * -> !
foreign import data Obj :: *
foreign import data FirstObjSrc :: *
foreign import data SecondObjSrc :: *

foreign import somePropImpl :: forall a s e. a -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) Boolean
foreign import toggleSomePropImpl :: forall a s e. a -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) Unit

foreign import someOtherPropImpl :: ...
foreign import doSomethingWithOtherPropImpl :: ...

foreign import getStateImpl :: forall a b s e. (a -> Maybe a) -> Maybe a -> b -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) (Maybe s)
foreign import setStateImpl :: forall a s e. a -> s -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) Unit


foreign import getFirstObjImpl :: forall a s e. FirstObjSrc -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) a
foreign import getSecondObjImpl :: forall a s e. SecondObjSrc -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) a


class MainObj a where
  someProp :: forall s e. a -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) Boolean
  toggleSomeProp :: forall s e. a -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) Unit

class FirstObj a where
  someOtherProp :: ...
  doSomethingWithOtherProp :: ...

class (MainObj a) <= SecondObj a where
  getState :: forall s e. a -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) (Maybe s)
  setState :: forall s e. a -> s -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) Unit

class ObjSrc a where
  getObj :: forall b s e. a -> Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) b


instance objIsMainObj :: MainObj Obj where
  someProp = somePropImpl
  toggleSomeProp = toggleSomePropImpl

instance objIsFirstObj :: FirstObj Obj where
  someOtherProp = someOtherPropImpl
  doSomethingWithOtherProp = doSomethingWithOtherPropImpl

instance objIsSecondObj :: SecondObj Obj where
  getState = getStateImpl Just Nothing
  setState = setStateImpl

instance firstObjSrcIsObjSrc :: ObjSrc FirstObjSrc where
  getObj = getFirstObjImpl

instance secondObjSrcIsObjSrc :: ObjSrc SecondObjSrc where
  getObj = getSecondObjImpl

foreign import getFirstObjSrc :: forall s e. Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) FirstObjSrc
foreign import getSecondObjSrc :: forall s e. Eff (oe :: ObjEff s | e) SecondObjSrc
```

So, I have some questions about this code:

1. Is this implementation correct?
2. Does `ObjEff` effect require phantom type `s`?
3. If it does (or doesn't), then I'd like to understand why (I've read an explanation at https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type and some other ones and I think that I understand the basics, but effects confuse me a little).

**Update**

Let's say that the code above is some kind of imaginary browser (or NodeJS) API, so there is no way to change it somehow.

Comment: One of the cornerstones of functional programming is to have data structures that are immutable and to keep any mutable state to a minimum.  Don't have mutable data structures, have your toggle function take an old data structure as an argument, and return a new data structure that contains the new value.

Comment: @Bzzt This question is not about `toggleSomeProp`, it's about `state`. `toggleSomeProp` is just a noise that can be replaced with `...`. The code above is simplified version of browser native code, so in reality there's no way I can have my toggle function take an old data structure as an argument. `Event` and `CustomEvent` may be good examples.

Comment: I'd check out libs like purescript-simple-dom and see how they do it there.  For a different approach, purescript-halogen uses virtual-dom.

Comment: @Bzzt `Virtual-dom` is about rendering, not about event listening. And `purescript-simple-dom` has no support for custom events. And actually because of the way `removeEventListener` is implemented there I am a little suspicious about this lib.

Answer (score 0):

This question is based on an older and incompatible version of the language than is current. `Eff` and effect rows have been removed and in its place is `Effect` (essentially `Eff` sans effect rows). I am guessing `*` has been replaced by `Type` and `!` was removed (Those notations did not exist when I began using PureScript).

The notation used for objects is a bit confusing because it is neither JavaScript nor any other standard notation I am familiar with. My interpretation is that, for example,

```
MainObj {
  someProp: false
  toggleSomeProp: function () {
    if (this.someProp)
      this.someProp = false
    else
      this.someProp = true
  }
  ...
}
```

Means this (in JavaScript)

```
function MainObj() {
}
MainObj.prototype.someProp = false;
MainObj.prototype.toggleSomeProp = function () {
  if (this.someProp)
    this.someProp = false
  else
    this.someProp = true
}
// ...
```

In which case a possible definition for this in PureScript is:

```
foreign import data MainObj ∷ Type

foreign import someProp ∷ MainObj → Effect Boolean

foreign import toggleSomeProp ∷ MainObj → Effect Unit
```

And the implementation file would be:

```
exports.someProp = function (mainObj) {
  return function () {
    return mainObj.someProp;
  };
};

exports.toggleSomeProp = function (mainObj) {
  return function () {
    return mainObj.toggleSomeProp();
  };
}
```

Or for better inlining and easier implementation, this:

```
foreign import data MainObj ∷ Type

foreign import someProp ∷ EffectFn1 MainObj Boolean

foreign import toggleSomeProp ∷ EffectFn1 MainObj Unit
```

And the implementation would be:

```
exports.someProp = function (mainObj) {
  return mainObj.someProp;
};

exports.toggleSomeProp = function (mainObj) {
  return mainObj.toggleSomeProp();
}
```

There are various ways this could be done (and are done) but this is the method I use almost exclusively because it is straight-forward, obvious, and highly adaptable.

`someProp` must be imported as effectful because given the same object it can return different results. `toggleSomeProp` must be imported as effectful because it mutates state in an observable way (through `someProp`).